# Access property on locked object, without lock statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Say I have the following code:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public int Var1{ get; set; }
}

public static void main( string[] args )
{
    var foo = new FooBar();
    //Start new thread ...
    {
        lock( foo )
        {
            foo.Var1 = 1;
            Thread.Sleep( 10000 );
        }
    }

    //Start another thead ...
    {
        Console.WriteLine( foo.Var1 );
    }
}
```

Will the second thread be able to access the property and write to the console while the other thread is sleeping and have the lock, or will it have to wait until the other thread finishes sleeping and exists?

Comment: Locking is only useful when the 2 threads can lock on the same object.  It's unclear here if both threads can access the local `object` to lock on.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean? Both threads here can acceess the object, however one specifies that it wants to lock the object while the other just attempts to read a property from it.

My point is, will the second thread actually 'check' the lock on the object since I haven't specified it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in doubt just test it:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new FooBar();
        foo.Var1 = 0;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(NewThread));
        t.Start(foo);

        lock (foo)
        {
            foo.Var1 = 1;
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            foo.Var1 = 2;
        }
    }
    public static void NewThread(object foo)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine((foo as FooBar).Var1);
    }

}
```

This proves YES it can access it even if another thread has it locked. However if you chose to lock the variable in the NewThread method before you read from it it would get blocked.

Comment: Can you explain why another thread in this case can access a locked resource? Are you saying both threads must have the same lock? I'm not an expert on threading but if so that's a pretty shi**y lock.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that we don't tell the other thread to check for the lock, with the 'lock' keyword. So it just reads from the property.
However, if we did tell the other thread to attempt to lock aswell, it can't and therefore it waits until the other thread unlocks.

Comment: @Capsup You may be right. But when I think about reality e.g. if there is a lock on a door I simply can't open that door unless I have the key of course.  I hope this is not a case of "it is a feature not a bug". I thought a lock was supposed to act as a memory fence.

Comment: @Lews Locking a resource doesn't mean no one else can access it or even write to it. It just means no one else can lock it without having to wait until the original lock is released.

Comment: @CeejeeB ? It should mean exactly that. If thread1 acquires a lock, then other threads must wait for thread1 to release the lock.

Comment: @Lews I guess it all depends on how your interpret the word lock. You will have to take it up with Microsoft.

Comment: @CeejeeB Well it is a *lock*. How else should it be interpreted? :P

Comment: @Lews Locking a door just holds the door in place, it doesn't mean you can't paint the door red or remove the door knocker :P

Comment: @CeejeeB Lulz, I'm not sure how painting a locked door or removing the door knock can unlock the door. The resource in this analogy is what is behind the door :)

Comment: @Lews No the door is the object and its colour and knocker are its properties. Just because it is locked it doesn't mean they cant be changed, BUT it does mean no one else can look the door.

Comment: @CeejeeB The way I think of it is: `lock(door)\t access critical section`

Comment: Your example is different than the question. In the question, he makes a new thread to `lock` and sleep. In your answer, you are doing that operation on the MainThread. You have done it the correct way, however it will produce a slightly different result than the question.

Comment: @LewsTherin Lock allows you to create a fence/critical section, and prevent anybody else from entering *that critical section* (or any other critical section using the same object as a "key").  It doesn't have any effect at all on the object used as a "key" in the lock...  The object is merely a way to "track" usage.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I understand that.. I will have a chat with you about it later :)

Comment: @LewsTherin The statement `lock(door) { doWork(); }` does not mean do not allow anyone else to use the `door`. It means in order to perform `doWork()`, you must lock the door. If the door is already locked, it cannot be locked again by anyone else (however, you can lock it over and over yourself, by yourself meaning the same thread). If another person wants to do some other work, it is free to do so. But as soon as the other person wishes to do some work and also wants to lock the same door, then it must wait.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new FooBar();

        // new thread which tries to change the property foo.Var1
        FooBarChanger changer = new FooBarChanger(ref foo);
        var subThread = new Thread(changer.TryChange);
        subThread.IsBackground = true;
        subThread.Start();

        lock (foo)
        {
            foo.Var1 = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("main - lock: {0}", foo.Var1);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("main - lock: updated value: {0}", foo.Var1);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class FooBarChanger
{
    private FooBar _b;

    public FooBarChanger(ref FooBar b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public void TryChange()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("subthread: changing value now!");
        _b.Var1 = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("subthread: {0}", _b.Var1);
    }
}

public class FooBar
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
}
```

the code below is able to change the value of the property and creates the following output:

main - lock: 1
subthread: changing value now!
subthread: 100
main - lock: updated value: 100

hope i could help you a bit :)
Toby